# implement the recognition of mnist datasets, the Segmentation fault (core dumped) is displayed

Tags: c

I want to use C language to implement the recognition of mnist datasets, using a backpropagation algorithm, but when loading the input layer neural units, the Segmentation fault (core dumped) is displayed, here's the code snippet, why, and how to solve it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define PATH_TRAIN_IMAGES "../../train-images-idx3-ubyte"
#define PATH_TRAIN_LABELS "../../train-labels-idx1-ubyte"
#define PATH_WEIGHT_DATA2 "../data/data2.weight"
#define PATH_WEIGHT_DATA3 "../data/data3.weight"
#define PATH_BIAS_DATA2 "../data/data2.bias"
#define PATH_BIAS_DATA3 "../data/data3.bias"
#define TRAIN_IMAGES_NUMBER 60000
#define PIXEL 784
#define HIDDEN_UNITS_NUMBER 300
#define OUT_UNITS_NUMBER 10
#define TRAIN_TEST 0

struct Unit
{
    // input with weight
    float z;
    // bias
    float b;
    // output
    float a;
};


float sigmod(float z)
{
    return (1 / (1 + exp(-z)));
}


struct Unit* create_unit(float uz, float ub, float ua)
{
    struct Unit* unit = (struct Unit*)malloc(sizeof(struct Unit));
    unit->z = uz;
    unit->b = ub;
    unit->a = ua;
    return unit;
}

int load_train_labels(char* path_train_labels, unsigned char* ar_label)
{
    FILE *fp_label;
    int size_label = 0;
    fp_label = fopen(path_train_labels, "rb");
    fseek(fp_label, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_label = ftell(fp_label);
    printf("%s size：%d byte\n", path_train_labels, size_label);
    rewind(fp_label);
    // Starting with the 9th byte
    fseek(fp_label,8,SEEK_SET);
    unsigned char train_labels_buffer[size_label];
    ar_label = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * size_label - 8);
    fread(ar_label, 1, size_label - 8, fp_label);
    fclose(fp_label);
    return size_label;
}



int load_train_images(char* path_train_images, unsigned char* ar_img)
{
    FILE *fp_img;
    int size_img = 0;
    fp_img = fopen(path_train_images, "rb");
    fseek(fp_img, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_img = ftell(fp_img);
    printf("%s size：%d byte\n", path_train_images, size_img);
    rewind(fp_img);
    // Starting with the 17th byte, each byte stores the value of one pixel in a picture
    fseek(fp_img, 16, SEEK_SET);
    ar_img = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_img - 16);
    fread(ar_img, 1, size_img - 16, fp_img);
    fclose(fp_img);
    return size_img;
}


int load_data(char* path_data, unsigned char* ar_data)
{
    FILE *fp_data;
    int size_data;
    fp_data = fopen(path_data, "rb");
    fseek(fp_data, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_data = ftell(fp_data);
    fseek(fp_data, 0, SEEK_SET);
    ar_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_data);
    printf("%s size：%d byte\n", path_data, size_data);
    return size_data;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Loading train labels file.\n");
    unsigned char* ar_label;
    int size_label;
    size_label = load_train_labels(PATH_TRAIN_LABELS, ar_label);


    printf("Loading train images file.\n");
    unsigned char* ar_img;
    int size_img;
    size_img = load_train_images(PATH_TRAIN_IMAGES, ar_img);


    printf("Loading random weight file.\n");
    unsigned char* ar_weight2;
    int size_weight2;
    size_weight2 = load_data(PATH_WEIGHT_DATA2, ar_weight2);
    unsigned char* ar_weight3;
    int size_weight3;
    size_weight3 = load_data(PATH_WEIGHT_DATA3, ar_weight3);


    printf("Loading random bias file.\n");
    unsigned char* ar_bias2;
    int size_bias2;
    size_bias2 = load_data(PATH_BIAS_DATA2, ar_bias2);
    unsigned char* ar_bias3;
    int size_bias3;
    size_bias3 = load_data(PATH_BIAS_DATA3, ar_bias3);


    float uz = 0;
    float ub = 0;
    float ua = 0;
    struct Unit* out_units[OUT_UNITS_NUMBER];
    for (int t = 0; t < OUT_UNITS_NUMBER; t++)
    {
        out_units[t] = create_unit(uz, ub, ua);
    }
    struct Unit* hid_units[HIDDEN_UNITS_NUMBER];
    for(int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_UNITS_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        hid_units[i] = create_unit(uz, ub, ua);
    }
    struct Unit* in_units[PIXEL] = {NULL};
    for(int i = 0; i < PIXEL; i++)
    {
        in_units[i] = create_unit(uz, ub, ua);
    }



     /*******************
      *    load   C1    *
      *******************/
    printf("Loading train...\n");
    float C[TRAIN_IMAGES_NUMBER];
    for(int i = 0; i < PIXEL; i++)
    {
        in_units[i]->a = (float)*((ar_img+i*sizeof(char)));  //segmentation fault(core dumped)
        printf("in_unit[%d] = %f\n", i, in_units[i]->a);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < HIDDEN_UNITS_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < PIXEL; j++)
        {
            hid_units[i]->z += in_units[j]->a * ((float)*(ar_weight2+((i*PIXEL+j)*sizeof(float))));
        }
        hid_units[i]->z += ((float)*(ar_bias2+(i*sizeof(float))));
        hid_units[i]->a = sigmod(hid_units[i]->z);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < OUT_UNITS_NUMBER; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < HIDDEN_UNITS_NUMBER; j++)
        {
            out_units[i]->z += hid_units[j]->a * ((float)*(ar_weight3+((i*HIDDEN_UNITS_NUMBER+j)*sizeof(float))));
        }
        out_units[i]->z += ((float)*(ar_bias3 + (i*sizeof(float))));
        out_units[i]->a = sigmod(out_units[i]->z);
    }

    // free(in_units)
    free(ar_label);
    free(ar_img);
    free(ar_weight2);
    free(ar_bias2);
    free(ar_weight3);
    free(ar_bias3);

    return 0;
}
```

Almost all source code was uploaded. I used the gdb debugger, but only showed Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.And I turned on ulimit, but didn't find the core file.

Comment: Use a debugger to get some hints of what the error is (it may even find you the error). Let me give a hint- you are defining the struct in the loop, with size of i, and then access i-th element.

Comment: Also I do not see a definition of `k`. Please provide a complete code example.

Comment: @PhilMasteG I uploaded almost all the source code, can you see where the problem is ?

Comment: @user1234 I used the gdb debugger. However, the valid information could not be displayed. Also ulimit didn't work this time..

Answer (score 1):

Your pointer-passing is flawed. When calling a function and passing that function a pointer to something, you can alter the data the pointer is pointing to, but not the address of the pointer itself so that it is visible from the caller perspective (only in the callees perspective).

For example, one of your functions signature reads:

```
int load_data(char* path_data, unsigned char* ar_data)
```

In that function, you do a

```
ar_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_data);
```

This is fine, but this does not effect, that the caller of the function `load_data` can access this allocated memory. Instead this memory address is lost as soon as that function returns.

This means, that when you write

```
unsigned char* ar_label;
int size_label;
size_label = load_train_labels(PATH_TRAIN_LABELS, ar_label);
```

then after calling the function, `ar_label` still has its original (uninitialized) value. What you probably meant to do was to write the function signature as (notice the extra asterisks/ampersands in the following):

```
int load_data(char* path_data, unsigned char** ar_data)
```

Then, allocate the memory as:

```
*ar_data = (unsigned char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * size_data);
```

and use the function as:

```
unsigned char* ar_label;
int size_label;
size_label = load_train_labels(PATH_TRAIN_LABELS, &ar_label);
```

This way, you are passing a pointer to a pointer and therefore can alter the address the pointer ar_label points to in the caller. This means, that this way you store the address of the `malloc`ated memory block in the callers pointer variable instead of in a copy of the pointer variable supplied as parameter. And you therefore are allowed to access the memory this pointer points to in the caller afterwards.